# How to release os_log_t types returned by os_log_create() on macOS?

Tags: macos

I'm writing a device driver (Kext) for macOS. I'm including logging via the `os_log_create` function which returns a log object.

I have not been able to find any corresponding method to release the returned object once I'm finished with it. The [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging/os_log_t?language=objc) does not describe how to release the object returned by `os_log_create`.

Should I be calling `os_release()` on this object when I'm done with it?

Here's an example of how I'm using `os_log_create()`:

```
VDDriverLib::VDDriverLib()
{
    logHandle = os_log_create("com.example.driver.driver-lib", "default");
};
```

Answer (score 8):

When documentation is silent about that (which is dumb), the header file `<os/log.h>` isn't. When you scroll down to the declaration of `os_log_create()` you can find info, that you should use `os_release()`.

Copy paste, in case someone would like to have immediate confirmation:

```
/*!
 * @function os_log_create
 *
 * @abstract
 * Creates a log object to be used with other log related functions.
 *
 * @discussion
 * Creates a log object to be used with other log related functions.  The
 * log object serves two purposes:  (1) tag related messages by subsystem
 * and category name for easy filtering, and (2) control logging system
 * behavior for messages.
 *
 * @param subsystem
 * The identifier of the given subsystem should be in reverse DNS form
 * (i.e., com.company.mysubsystem).
 *
 * @param category
 * The category within the given subsystem that specifies the settings for
 * the log object.
 *
 * @result
 * Returns an os_log_t value to be passed to other os_log API calls.  This
 * should be called once at log initialization and rely on system to detect
 * changes to settings.  This object should be released when no longer used
 * via os_release or -[release] method.
 *
 * A value will always be returned to allow for dynamic enablement.
 */
API_AVAILABLE(macos(10.12), ios(10.0), watchos(3.0), tvos(10.0))
OS_EXPORT OS_NOTHROW OS_WARN_RESULT OS_OBJECT_RETURNS_RETAINED OS_NONNULL_ALL
os_log_t
os_log_create(const char *subsystem, const char *category);
```

Comment: Not applicable to OP (since it's C++), but note that if you're using Objective-C with ARC you don't need to call `os_release()` because `os_log_t` is declared to be treated as an Objective-C object (in fact, doing so will cause a compilation error).